# Optional column in MSSQL User-Defined table types

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

I have a user defined table type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UDT_MyTable] AS TABLE(
    col1 int NULL,
    col2 int NULL,
    col3 int NULL
)
```

This type is being passed to procedures and being used from several places in the code.

Recently, one of the places that uses this type is needed to add another column.

So I modified the type and of course update the procedures which uses this type to use the new type by the procedure: sp_refreshsqlmodule
so now the type is:

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UDT_MyTable] AS TABLE(
    col1 int NULL,
    col2 int NULL,
    col3 int NULL,
    Col4 INT NULL default(0) 
)
```

The place which pass the forth column was update but I want to avoid all the places refer this table.

All the other places which call procedure which gets this datatype gets:

> Trying to pass a table-valued parameter with 3 column(s) where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 4 column(s).

I want to avoid changing all the places refer to this type to pass the forth parameter nor use "DEFAULT" as parameter.

I simply want to be able to pass 3 columns and the SQL will know to add the forth by itself.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Change the column to NOT NULL and keep the default. Then when a value is not provided for Col4 it will populate with the default.

Comment: My interpretation is NO. The type is very specific and your code must create the correct type in order to pass it as a parameter. There are ways around changing the code that populates the parameter with rows but the code must create a UDDT with those 4 columns. You will need to at least change the creation part. You can then ignore the column when adding rows by allowing null or using a default.

Comment: If you are calling the procedure from T-SQL then yes, but I expect you are using a `SqlDbType.Structured` parameter in something like C#? Then I believe the answer is no. If you are passing in an `IEnumerable` of `SqlDataRecord` or a `DataTable` I *believe* the structure of those elements must have 4 columns, but as SMor said, you don't have to populate them all. As an alternative you could rename the 4 column proc, create a new table type for it, then create a wrapper proc that takes the original 3 column type and calls the 4 column proc.  Old code uses the wrapper, you call the inner proc.

Comment: If using `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` then you can set `SqlMetaData.UseServerDefault`